# SVG feImage filter clips stroke - how to stop that?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to create a filter for *only* the stroke of path in SVG, but the `feImage` keeps getting clipped to what I assume is that bounding box (see green rectangle below in code as bounding box). I've tried setting the `filter`'s x/y and width/height to all sorts of positions/sizes, as seems to be the prevailing advice, but nothing works. x/y just offset the `feImage` and width/height of greater than 100% has no effect.

I won't know in advance if the stroke or fill is solid or something else (like `linearGradient`.

The below demonstrates what I'm looking to do - just get the stroke of a shape (regardless of size or fill) and apply a filter to it for all modern browsers.

Notes: FF doesn't even display the left-hand `feImage`. Chrome clips the left and top. Edge clips all 4 sides.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="960" height="540" >
      <rect width="960" height="540" stroke="#385D8A" fill="white" stroke-width="3"/>
      <svg name="BoundingBox1" class="rect" x="100" y="100" overflow="visible" fill="none" stroke="#00ff00"  stroke-width="1">
        <path d="M0,0L121.68,0L121.68,121.68L0,121.68Z" />
      </svg>
      <!-- BELOW IS MODIFIED "SPEECH" SHAPE. NEED A FILTER ON THE STROKE ONLY. -->
      <svg name="Speech-strokeonly" x="100" y="100" overflow="visible" fill="blue" stroke="orange" stroke-width="12" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            

          <path d="M35.541,137.084L30.985,113.988A60.926,60.926 0 1 1 53.043,121.34Z" id="strokeOnly" fill="none"/>
          
          <filter id="effs0sp9" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="0" y="0">
            <feImage xlink:href="#strokeOnly"  />
          </filter>
          
        </defs>
        
        <path d="M35.541,137.084L30.985,113.988A60.926,60.926 0 1 1 53.043,121.34Z" id="effs0sp9" filter="url(#effs0sp9)" overflow="visible" />
        <text y="160" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2">this is the one that has undesirable clipping of</text>
        <text y="178" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2">of stroke in Chrome/Edge. Doesn't appear at all in FF</text>
      </svg>
      <!-- BELOW IS ORIGINAL WITH BOTH FILL AND STROKE -->
      <svg name="BoundingBox2" x="400" y="100" overflow="visible" fill="none" stroke="green"  stroke-width="1">
        <path d="M0,0L121.68,0L121.68,121.68L0,121.68Z" />
      </svg>
      
      <svg name="Speech-original" x="400" y="100" overflow="visible" fill="blue" stroke="orange"  stroke-width="12">
        
        <path d="M35.541,137.084L30.985,113.988A60.926,60.926 0 1 1 53.043,121.34Z" id="effs0sp9"  />
        <text y="-22" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2">this is the original one</text>
        <text y="-6" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2">that I just want the stroke as feImage from</text>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to grab the whole stroke of a shape only and use in a filter?

Comment: Firefox only supports feImage if it points to a complete image file (or a data URI equivalent to such a file).

Comment: Yeah, I saw a bug about that from like 11 years ago. But that was 11 years ago, so I got to thinking at the development team might have done some work between now and then.

Comment: You mean like fixing more than [2000 bugs and enhancements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?chfield=%5BBug%20creation%5D&chfieldfrom=-11y&chfieldto=Now&component=SVG&known_name=SVG%20Updates&list_id=14843782&product=Core&query_format=advanced&resolution=FIXED&order=changeddate%2Cbug_status%2Cpriority%2Cassigned_to%2Cbug_id&limit=0)

Comment: There are still places where SVG 1.1 has not been completely implemented in all browsers. Safari is definitely the worst, but Chrome has gaps too. The workaround for Firefox is to URI encode the content you want to pull into feImage.